# json_encode russia language

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with encode russia language on a server, this code don't work there
`json_encode($data['block'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

field in db have

`"[{\"type\":\"content\",\"data\":{\"content\":\"<blockquote>\\n<p>\u0412\u0435\u0440\u043e\u044f\u0442\u043d\u043e,`

but on my localhost all is work. This field from my localhost-db
`"[{\"type\":\"content\",\"data\":{\"content\":\"<p>Это работает<\\/p>\"}}]"`

What is written below is on localhost
My $data["block"] have:

```
array:1 [▼ 
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "content"
    "data" => array:1 [▼
      "content" => "<p>Это должно сработать редактируюd</p>"
    ]
  ]
]
```

It's json $data['content']:

```
"[{"type":"content","data":{"content":"<p>Это должно сработать редактирую<\/p>"}}]"
```

My local db have that record after `$data['content'] = json_encode($data['block'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

[image]

Comment: Remember that you receive data from the browser in urlencoded form, not in plain text. You have to first decode it to normal text before you do anything with it.

Comment: Seems obvious that nobody will be able to help without knowing what is in `$data["block"]` or how you are verifying the database contents? If you specify `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` it won't escape the Unicode so something else must be doing it

Comment: Looks like double-encoded JSON to me. They're probably receiving a JSON blob from somewhere else that already has escapes, and wondering why adding a second layer of encoding doesn't "fix" it.

Comment: @miken32, i'm updated question